# Post to twitter, improve security

Tags: security, twitter, passwords

I have a web site and every client has his own account. When clients create new articles, titles should go to their own twitter accounts.

The question is how to make it in background? I can ask user for twitter login/password - and save this data in my database. But the problem is with security: password will be stored unencrypted.

Does twitter have better way to organize this flow?

thank you

p.s.
to make it clear - background sending is must - as some clients use API to access my services

Comment: Read up on their API documentation (http://dev.twitter.com/doc)

Comment: It sounds like you have three questions here: 1) how do I make use of OAuth so my users can authorize my application while giving me safe credentials I can store, and 2) How do I use my users' stored credentials to post status updates to their Twitter accounts, and 3) how do I make the status posting happen in the background.  I'd start with question 1 first, and then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is the solution to your problem. OAuth is supported by Twitter.

By using OAuth, each of your users may authorize you to post tweets on their behalf. You will get a token for each user. You must store this token in your database, but you will not need the end users username or password.